# Cloudant Dashboard is not launching in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Logged in to IBM Cloud and created Cloudant NoSQL DB service.
After launching **Cloudant Dashboard**, I am getting folling error :

```
{
      "statusCode": 401,
      "message": "'https://broker.eu-gb.cloudantnosqldb.cloud.ibm.com/sso_dashboard?spaceId=34e3fe3e-b59a-48bc-9bb7-0c33fd14e831&instanceId=da0fa2ff-50eb-43af-86d1-4bc0aed1406b' is not a valid redirect_uri for client CloudantClientId"
    }
```

region/location I have tried - UK / Sydney

Any Suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: You can open a support ticket by following the instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.0.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.doc/support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a defect - please open a support ticket as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.0.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.doc/support.html

---

*I’m mirroring [Glynn Bird’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264864/glynn-bird) comment as an answer so this question can be accepted and closed.*